# React JS - Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function ES lint Error

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm checking if the env is development or prod, If `development` I'm returning mock data else I'm making an API call to fetch data.

Now I'm getting this ES lint Error,

> Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function.

What I'm doing wrong here ? please help

```
export const getData = (request: any) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
    axios.post(EMAIL_DISPUTE_API, { request })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  } else {
    return emailDisputeMockResponse;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of your function,if block don't return value but else return `emailDisputeMockResponse`, so you need declare return value type for your function and return value in the catch block, just like following code snippet

```js
export const getData = async (request: any): Promise<emailDisputeResponse | null> => {
  let result: emailDisputeResponse | null
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
    result = await axios.post(EMAIL_DISPUTE_API, { request })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
      });
  } else {
    result = emailDisputeMockResponse;
  }
  return result
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Requires return statements to either always or never specify values.

Try without else bloc

```js
export const getData = (request: any) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
    axios.post(EMAIL_DISPUTE_API, { request })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
    return emailDisputeMockResponse;
};
```